# Is [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] harmless in all situations?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, asmx

I'm developing a web service to be used by our customers for a specific processing purpose. Visual Studio adds a line to the top of my asmx file that tells:

```
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

I'm not sure in which different scenarios, this web service will be used and because of that I cannot decide on leaving it commented or uncomment it.

My question is that, is it harmless to uncomment it for all situation or making so might lead to security problems?

Answer (score -2):

If your code is using your .asmx file, then Please do not change anything in the .asmx file.

because `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` is require for .asmx file. if you remove this line your service method will not call and resulting in error.

Comment: Sir. This line is commented by default. I will not use my web service but i am developing it for my customers. The webservice will sure work in certain scenarios but i am not sure if removing that comment will make web service volnerable in certain conditions.